# 'require' statement in index.js causes error saying mailchimp module cannot be found

Tags: node.js, module, mailchimp

I'm using this API for a web app I'm making that uses mailchimp:
[Here's the node.js API page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailchimp-api?__hstc=72727564.6fd9939c0873b0cfb90da1447cdbb9ef.1422159044178.1422159044178.1422159044178.1&__hssc=72727564.1.1422159044178&__hsfp=2845238507)

I'm also using this git repo to understand how to use the API: [example repo](https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-node-examples)

I cloned the repo, ran `npm install express` in the express directory of the repo, then ran `node app`

when I did that, I got this error: `Error: Cannot find module './node_modules/mailchimp-api/mailchimp'`

The require statement that names this module (in index.js) is:

```
var mcapi = require('./node_modules/mailchimp-api/mailchimp');
```

I checked the path, it should be correct. is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `npm install` in the express directory of the repo so that all of the modules are installed. You are missing the mailchimp module.